# How to properly pass variables through different functions PYTHON

Tags: python

I am working on a hangman game for a couple days. I am currently making the functions. I've researched how to pass a local variable to another function, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am assuming the problem is with **theme = start().** When I run the program it completely ignores what the user enters as the theme and go straight to the else statement and prints  *"That wasn't an option"* even if the user types in one of the options correctly. How can I get python to realize that the theme in **def sub_theme()** is History(or whatever the user types in but in this case I'm just using history) and to then continue from there?

```
def start():
    print("Welcome to hangman!!!")
    print("Let's get started.")
    theme = input("Okay I'll pick a word, all you have to do is pick a theme :) \n Themes to pick from: History, Companies, Geography, Music, Movies, Celebrities, and Sports Team! ")

    return theme



def sub_theme():    
    #### If the user chooses History as their option ####
    theme = start()
    if theme.casefold() == 'History':
        print("So your options are: Presidents or Vice Presidents.")
        user_theme = input("So what's your choice? ")


        if user_theme.casefold() == "Presidents":
            secret_word = "George Washington"
            print(secret_word)
            print(secret_word)

    #### if they type in something besides the options ####
    else: 
        print("That wasn't an option.")
        return

def hide_word():
    #hides the word with underscores
    hide = ""
    secret_word = sub_theme()
    for letter in secret_word:

        if letter in [" " , "," , ":" , "'" , "-" , "_" , "&" , "é", '"', "/" , "." , "?" , "!"]:
            hide = hide + letter

        else:
            hide = hide + "_ "

    print(hide)
    return(hide)

def play():
    hide_word()

play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `string.casefold() == "History"` will never be true because `casefold` acts as a `lower` but more aggressive. Just change "History" to "history" and it'll work.

Second, you might want to look into [classes](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/). 
That way you can make `theme` (or anything else, in this case secret_word) a self attribute and access it from all functions of your class without having to pass it between them.

Here's a quick working mookup of conversion for the code you provided:

```
class Hangman:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Welcome to hangman!!!")
        print("Let's get started.")
        theme = input("Okay I'll pick a word, all you have to do is pick a theme :) \n"
                      "Themes to pick from: History, Companies, Geography, Music, Movies, "
                      "Celebrities, and Sports Team! ")

        if theme.casefold() == 'history':
            print("So your options are: Presidents or Vice Presidents.")
            user_theme = input("So what's your choice? ")


            if user_theme.casefold() == "presidents":
                self.secret_word = "George Washington"

        else:
            print("That wasn't an option.")
            return

        self.hide_word()

    def hide_word(self):
        hide = ""
        for letter in self.secret_word:

            if letter in [" " , "," , ":" , "'" , "-" , "_" , "&" , "é", '"', "/" , "." , "?" , "!"]:
                hide = hide + letter

            else:
                hide = hide + "_ "

        print(hide)


Hangman()
```